# How to make .jar file from custom java class in android-studio for use other project

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio

I create my android application in android-studio it's work well.

In my project has my custom 3 class "ClassA.java", "ClassB.java" and "ClassC.java"

I want to convert 3 class to 1 java libary file(.jar) for use in another project.

How can i do it's? Please let me know step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Java only gradle project.

1. Create a new directory elsewhere.
2. Create a build.gradle file there and don't apply the android plugin, just apply "java".
3. Create src/main/java directory structure and move your code there.
4. Add any needed dependencies to the build file.
5. "./gradle build" will create your jar,
6. You can publish the jar to an artifact repo (locally or to someplace like [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter)) using a plugin such as [gradle-mvn-push](https://github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push)
7. Then any project that needs your 3 classes can add a maven or gradle dependency.

If your classes depend on Android you will want to make an "aar" instead of a jar.

Comment: i create .aar file success but. how to use it's in another project. I do same .jar file(coppy to libs folder and in build.gradle "dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar') compile files('libs/framework.aar')}" ) no error but i can not find my class to import it's to my activity